# Create new shapefile layer per raster layer

Tags: qgis, shapefile, masking, image-segmentation, deep-learning

In QGIS i have several hundreds raster tiles. For a deep learning application i would like to create segementation masks. To achieve this, my approach is to make a new shapefile, create the polygon for the desired area and export it to json format afterwards. This works fine for a single file. But annotating several hundreds and therefore naming these separately seems like an avoidable necessity.

Is there a better way to part automate the shapelayer creation with naming or has anybody experience with annotating tiff files with QGIS for deep learning?

Comment: Are you looking for `QGIS - Raster - Miscellaneous - Tile Index` function? It will create the bounding box for each of the raster's as a new "unique-name" shapefile.

Comment: That was not exactly what i was looking for but helps definitely as well! My intention was to store each vector layer with the contained polygons as separate geojson named like the tile they belong to. Could you think of a solution to this?